# FileNotFoundException - The Process cannot access the file

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I have a network drive at school, I have the ability to read and write to it normally, but when I use java to take an existing text file and try and write to it, I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: p:\CompSci_CheckIn_Name.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

I can read it just fine and all but when I try and write to it, it throws me an exception. I can write to my desktop and read and everything from my desktop but when I try my network drive, it gives up. How could I get around this problem?

#### Reading

```
file = new File(directories[i], "CompSci_CheckIn_Name.txt");
readName = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
userName = readName.readLine();
passed = true;
```

#### Writing

```
write = new PrintWriter(file);
write.println(newUser);
write.flush();
userName = newUser;
write.close();
```

I have already tried a `BufferedWriter` with no luck, same result.

Comment: Is the file open in any other program, or even your IDE when you attempt to write to the file?

Comment: No it is not, I'm wondering do you think the network drive could prevent any code from writing to it? To prevent any software doing that? But word and stuff works, so what gives :(

Comment: My next question was going to be whether what ever you are running your code with could be running under a different user? If so, there is a good chance that could affect things. Are you using an IDE or using the command line to run the application?

Comment: Maybe you dont have write permissions to the file.

Comment: It's running under the main user that has I'm almost positive administrator privileges. And I am using blue j too for my IDE.

Comment: I think I'm going to add some other features in that can be put into place instead of that, and when our school gives a labtop to everyone next year they could reenable the reading and writing to a text file for easier access, etc. but for now, the damn network drive wins, I give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `close()` `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` after using them.

Use a try/finally block and close your `Reader`s in the finally block.

```
FileReader fr = null;
BufferdReader br = null;

try {
    fr = new FileRader(file);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // do something..

} finally {
    if (br != null) br.close();
    if (fr != null) fr.close();
}
```